# Search Server Express fails to provide results after changing content source to FQDN

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, central-administration, configuration, alternate-access-mapping

I have SP Foundation site which is running Search Server Express.

When the site collection, IIS, and SSE are configured for a FQDN rather than the default machine name, **the crawling service completes, but does not crawl past the root, and thus returns no search results.**

I have added a document library with text files. When the site is configured only for the machine name, e.g. the sharepoint default (http://mymachine_name) the search crawls correctly and finds all of the files.

**What am I missing with the configuration? Is the process similar for configuring SSL?**

Here is the current configuration:

**IIS:**

[image: IIS Bindings]

**AAM:**[image: Alternate Access Mappings]

**SSE Full Crawl Results:**
[image: SSE Full Crawl Results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more extensive work in looking into this issue I was able to resolve this problem. If you are having similar problems, ensure the following:

1. Ensure that the GUID for the pdf key does not have any trailing white-space when you copy it! This is very easy to miss:

> "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server
>   Extensions\14.0\Search\Setup\ContentIndexCommon\Filters\Extension.pdf"
>
> "{E8978DA6-047F-4E3D-9C78-CDBE46041603}"

1. If you have SSL setup with an un-signed certificate, turn off SSL warnings for Search Server Express
2. Make sure you have configured your "Server Name Mapping":

> Address for indexing: 'http://portal.contoso.com'
>
> Address for display in search results: 'http://machineName'

1. Make sure that the PDF file type is added in Search Server Express
2. In certain configurations, you may need to disable LoopBackCheck and also disable StrictNameChecking (**understand the implications of these changes first! Check the microsoft KBs**):

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa